# How to delete an array of keys from a Postgres jsonb object?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` object that I want to remove keys from. I have a `jsonb` array that holds the keys that I want to remove from the object. I see documentation for deleting a single key, like this:

```
SELECT '{"foo": true, "bar": false, "baz": true}'::jsonb - 'foo'
```

Returns `{"bar": false, "baz": true}`

But I don't see any documentation on removing multiple keys at once, say from a Postgres or `jsonb` array. I'd like to do something along the lines of this pseudocode:

```
SELECT '{"foo": true, "bar": false, "baz": true}'::jsonb - '["foo", "bar"]'::jsonb
-- I'd like to return {"baz": true}
```

How can I delete an array of keys from a `jsonb` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-` operator with an array of `text` on the right hand side:

```
SELECT '{"foo": true, "bar": false, "baz": true}'::jsonb
       - '{foo,bar}'::text[];
```